# routeConfig.navModal is undefined - Aurelia

Tags: aurelia, routeconfig

I am using Aurelia for this first time. While doing the [contact manager tutorial](https://aurelia.io/docs/tutorials/creating-a-contact-manager), I faced a problem with `RouteConfig.navModal.title`. Everytime I try to trigger that line, I am getting

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.routeConfig.navModal is undefined
```

My Code looks something like this:

This is my .ts file:

```
async save() {
    await this.api.saveContact(this.selectedContact)
        .then((contact: IContact) => {
            this.selectedContact = {
                id: contact.id,
                firstName: contact.firstName,
                lastName: contact.lastName,
                email: contact.email,
                phoneNumber: contact.phoneNumber
            }
        });
    this.routeConfig.navModal.title = this.selectedContact.firstName;
    this.originalContact = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.selectedContact));
}
```

This my .html file, exactly where the button is triggered:

```
<div>
    <button 
        class="btn btn-success float-right"
        click.delegate="save()"
        disabled.bind="!canSave"
    >
      Save
    </button>
</div>
```

Also here is my api.saveContact method:

```
saveContact(contact: IContact){
    this.isRequesting = true;
    return new Promise<IContact>(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        let instance = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(contact));
        let found = contacts.filter(x => x.id == contact.id)[0];

        if(found){
          let index = contacts.indexOf(found);
          contacts[index] = instance;
          
        }else{
          instance.id = getId();
          contacts.push(instance);
        }

        this.isRequesting = false;
        resolve(instance);
      }, latency);
    });
  }
```

The whole issue is in line:

```
this.routeConfig.navModal.title = this.selectedContact.firstName;
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS. I also tried `this.routeConfig.navModal.setTitle(this.selectedContact.firstName);` that didnt work too.

Comment: The property name is `navModel` not `navModal` - it's a model of the navigation structure. Check your spelling - you have a typo/misread.

Comment: @Charleh oh dear, my bad, you are right! Thank you!